# Angular JS data response undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, json-server

I am new to Angular JS, and am trying to call Rest API using JSON data. When I run HTTP-server , am not getting back my response data.

```
function contacts(contactsdata) {
    contactsdata.getcontacts().then(function(data) {
        this.contactsinfo = data;
    });
}

(function(){ 
    var mod = angular.module('myapp');
    mod.controller("contacts", contacts);
    mod.service("contactsdata", function($http) {   
        this.getcontacts = function(){
            var execute1 = $http.get('http://localhost:3000/contacts');
            var execute2 = execute1.then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            })
            return execute2;
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in service

```
       this.getcontacts = function(){
           return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/contacts');
       });
```

And use as

```
contactsdata.getcontacts().then(function(response){
    this.contactsinfo = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues here.

1. Need to pass an empty array while initializing angular like this

   `var mod = angular.module('myapp', []);`
2. Need to inject the dependency of the service in the controller like this

   `mod.controller("contacts", ['$scope', 'contactsdata', contacts]);`
3. You can return the promise from the service like return `$http.get...` & use the data in the service

```js
function contacts($scope, contactsdata) {
  contactsdata.getcontacts().
  then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
}


(function() {
  var mod = angular.module('myapp', []);
  mod.controller("contacts", ['$scope', 'contactsdata', contacts]);
  mod.service("contactsdata", ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getcontacts = function() {
      return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    }
  }])

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="contacts"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) OP may have created the module elsewhere and is using the module getter `angular.module(moduleName)`

Comment: 2) DI annotations are only required when minifying code

Comment: Yes may be but that was not visible in the code snippet, so I have inject the dependency array

Comment: 3) OP **is** returning the promise from `$http`

Comment: when I run the above code. It's shows " contacts is not defined" @Phil

Comment: @kishore this isn't my answer, you want [brk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181397/brk)